# Ising model: How is $|\langle\sigma\rangle|^{2}=\lim _{r \rightarrow \infty} G^{(2)}(r)$?

Tags: field-theory, phase-transition, correlation-functions, ising-model

In the book of Statistical Field Theory by *Giuseppe Mussardo*, on page 51, it is given while talking about Ising model that

> One arrives to the same conclusion by analysing the possibility of a non-zero expectation value of the spin, i.e. a non-vanishing limit
> $$
> |\langle\sigma\rangle|^{2}=\lim _{r \rightarrow \infty} G^{(2)}(r)
> $$

where $G^2$ is the two-point correlation function and $\sigma_i$ would denote the spin at location $i$ (not exact sure what to understand is $\sigma$ doesn't contain an index).

How does the author derives/arrives this equality? I don't get it.

Comment: At large distances (compared with the correlation length), fluctuations in spins are uncorrelated, so $\langle \sigma(0)\sigma(r)\rangle - (\langle\sigma\rangle)^2$ approaches zero as $r\rightarrow\infty$.  The rigorous proof (that a correlation length exists) is somewhat nontrivial however.

Comment: @TLDR but what the equation in the question states is that the square of the mean of $\sigma$ is related to the correlation function. That is my question: how?

Comment: @TLDR The equation isn't talking about fluctuations, etc.

Comment: Do you see how statistical fluctuations are relevant to the definition of $G^{(2)}$?

Comment: @TLDR yes, but $|<\sigma>|^2$ isn't about fluctuations.

Comment: Neither is "=".

Comment: @TLDR Rigorous proof of what? There's certainly no rigorous proof that this is the spontaneous magnetization beyond 1D.

Comment: @TLDR I don't understand what you mean by your last comment

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Not sure what rigorous proof you're referring to, but the claim in the OP (once properly formulated) can be proved rigorously in great generality, see my answer (and the proof is rather easy in the Ising model).

Comment: @YvanVelenik I guess there are two possible statements one could read into the question/comment: (1) G decays (exponentially) to a constant. (2) This constant is the spontaneous magnetization. AFAIK (but you know better) the latter is not proven e.g. for the 2D classical Ising model (with the canonical definition of spontaneous magnetization, i.e. putting a small field and taking the limit field -> 0 after taking the tdyn. limit).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch both claims can indeed be proved in any dimension.

Comment: @Yvan Interesting. Who has proved this (for the 2D Ising model)?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch This is an old result. I’ll try to find the earliest reference tomorrow.

Comment: @Yvan All right - my understanding is that in the Lieb-Mattis-Schultz-RMP, this is an open problem (ok, this is very old), and my understanding was that it still was more recently (at least for some other models like Heisenberg).

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Ok, so who derived it first depends very much on the precise form of the statement (which state is used, etc.). An early reference,discussing also the previously established results, is Benettin *et al*,  Commun. Math. Phys. 30, 45-54 (1973).

Answer (score 1):

**A general statement.**

Let us first state a general result, valid in any dimension. Let $f$ and $g$ be two local functions (that is, functions depending only on finitely many spins). Then
$$
\lim_{|i|\to\infty} \langle f \cdot (g\circ\theta_i) \rangle^+ = \langle f \rangle^+  \langle g \rangle^+ , 
\tag{1}
$$
where I used $\theta_i$ to denote the translation by $i\in\mathbb{Z}^d$ and $\langle\cdot\rangle^+$ denotes the $+$ state (that is, the state obtained using $+$ boundary condition). Identity (1) is an easy consequence of the FKG inequality, see Exercise 3.15 in [this book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook) (note that its solution can be found in Appendix C).

**Application to the 2-point function.**

In particular, setting $f=g=\sigma_0$, Identity (1) reduces to
$$
\lim_{|i|\to\infty} \langle \sigma_0 \sigma_i \rangle^+ = \bigl( \langle \sigma_0 \rangle^+ \bigr)^2.
\tag{2}
$$
It can, in addition, be shown that $\langle \sigma_0 \rangle^+=m^*$, where $m^*$ denotes the spontaneous magnetization density (defined as the limit, as $h\downarrow 0$, of the magnetization density in the presence of a magnetic field $h$); see Remark 3.30 in the book.

**Extension to the free and periodic states**

Note that (2) (but not Identity (1) above) also holds for the state $\langle\cdot\rangle$ obtained using free or periodic boundary conditions.
This follows from the decomposition $\langle\cdot\rangle = \frac12 \langle\cdot\rangle^+ + \frac12 \langle\cdot\rangle^-$, combined with the identity $\langle\sigma_0\sigma_i\rangle^+ = \langle\sigma_0\sigma_i\rangle^-$:
$$
\lim_{|i|\to\infty} \langle \sigma_0 \sigma_i \rangle = \lim_{|i|\to\infty} \bigl( \tfrac12 \langle\sigma_0 \sigma_i\rangle^+ + \tfrac12 \langle\sigma_0 \sigma_i\rangle^-\bigr) = \lim_{|i|\to\infty} \langle \sigma_0 \sigma_i \rangle^+ = \bigl( \langle \sigma_0 \rangle^+ \bigr)^2.
$$
Note that it is still $m^*=\langle \sigma_0 \rangle^+$ that appears in the right-hand side (in fact, $\langle\sigma_0\rangle = 0$ by symmetry).

---

**Additional remarks:**

- Identity (1) is actually true for any extremal state in any model, but the proof is much more abstract (see Theorem 6.58 in [the same book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook)).
- The decomposition $\langle\cdot\rangle = \frac12 \langle\cdot\rangle^+ + \frac12 \langle\cdot\rangle^-$ is not a trivial fact (it is, for instance, not always true for the Ising model on a tree). It follows from the fact that the state $\langle\cdot\rangle$ is translation invariant and that all translation-invariant states are convex combinations of the states $\langle\cdot\rangle^+$ and $\langle\cdot\rangle^-$. Proofs can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409079) or [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.07608).